# Limiting Input Size ofTextField in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I want to get only numerical inputs how can i do it using `TextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField newTextField= new TextField ("Lines/Words:", "",3, TextField.NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TextField#setInputConstraints](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-0D0A1092-5037-4421-B466-B958CB777414/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html#constraints) to limit the input.